# Exceeded soft memory limit with basic SELECT

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a datastore with a kind named `MyUsers(db.Model)` that currently contains about 30 entities.
I have written a script that prints all the entities' "name" attribute to the screen (separated by the '#' char), using the following code:

```
def get(self):
    q_1 = MyUsers.all().order('name')
    for user in q_1:
        self.response.out.write(user.name)
        self.response.out.write("#")
```

The script works just fine, but the problem is that I always get critical message in the app engine log:

> 12-12 12:45AM 22.691
>
> Exceeded soft memory limit with
>   220.043 MB after servicing 1 requests total
>
> I 12-12 12:45AM 22.691
>
> This request caused a new process to
>   be started for your application, and
>   thus caused your application code to
>   be loaded for the first time. This
>   request may thus take longer and use
>   more CPU than a typical request for
>   your application.
>
> W 12-12 12:45AM 22.691
>
> After handling this request, the
>   process that handled this request was
>   found to be using too much memory and
>   was terminated. This is likely to
>   cause a new process to be used for the
>   next request to your application. If
>   you see this message frequently, you
>   may have a memory leak in your
>   application.

It seems like this is a very straightforward basic operation, that shouldn't exceed any memory limits, so what can I do to improve it?

Thanks,

Joel

---

EDIT:

As for the imports, the imports I use are:

```
from models.model import *
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import profiler.appengine.request
import profiler.appengine.datastore
```

I used a profiler to try and understand what is wrong, maybe you can help
[image: Debug from profiler]

Thanks!

Joel

---

**EDIT 2**

This is the full version of the code (the problem occurred also before I imported the profiler, I used it after it happened to try and debug):

```
from models.model import MyUsers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import profiler.appengine.request
import profiler.appengine.datastore

class PrintAll(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        q_1 = MyUsers.all().order('name')
        for user in q_1:
            self.response.out.write(user.name)
            self.response.out.write("#")

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/print', PrintAll)
                                      ],
                                     debug=True)

def main():

    profiler.appengine.request.activate()
    profiler.appengine.datastore.activate()

    run_wsgi_app(application)

    profiler.appengine.request.show_summary()
    profiler.appengine.datastore.show_summary()
    profiler.appengine.datastore.dump_requests() # optional

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As for the MyUsers() model class:

```
class MyUsers(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    points = db.FloatProperty()
    bonus = db.FloatProperty(default=0.0)
    joindate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    lastEntry=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name=db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    homepage = db.StringProperty()
    hobbies = db.ListProperty(str)
    other = db.StringProperty()
    calculate1 = db.FloatProperty()
    calculate2 = db.FloatProperty()
    calculate3= db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    history = db.ListProperty(str)
    history2 = db.ListProperty(str)
    title = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    title_string = db.StringProperty()
    updateDate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    level=db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    debug_helper=db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    debug_list=db.ListProperty(str)
```

Comment: Can you provide us any more details about your setup?  Maybe model defs, your imports, etc....

Comment: Please see the attached profiler results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, there's not really any way that this could cause the error you're seeing. Can you provide a complete reproduction case? It's likely that something other than the code snippet you've included is the cause of this issue.

Comment: I edited the question with imports and profiler output. thanks!

Comment: @Joel It seems likely that you're importing something that is consuming large amounts of memory. Are you using any frameworks? What's in your models module?

Comment: I am using the webapp framework. I edited the question again with the full code and the models class that I am importing (MyUsers)

Comment: @Joel Your 'MyUsers' model is rather large, and has a lot of lists. Just how big is a typical entity? Other than that, I really can't see how you're doing anything that could use up this much memory, which still leads me to believe there must be something you're doing that's not included in what you've pasted.

Comment: thanks! It seems that the problem really was the size of each entity. I optimized it and I no longer get that message.